# Expandable List View checkbox is checking multiple boxes

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-checkbox

I have a expandable list view with child check boxes.  The check box is defined in the child_helper xml with the id "check1".  For some reason it seems that multiple check boxes are linked together instead of each being independent.  For example if under the first group I select the first item, it chooses every 3rd item in that group and all the rest of the groups it selects the second item, skips two and selects the next item.

If I select the first three items in group 1 then it selects all items in all groups.  Somehow I have created 3 groups of check boxes instead of an individual check box for each child.  I have been looking at a lot of tutorials that suggest the problem is fixed with a custom adapter.  I am using a custom adapter, however, I am not sure how to use all of its functions.

Perhaps the better, and much shorter question is how am I supposed to differentiate each child check box?

Thanks

This is the code for my listener:

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Log.d( "Enter_Foods", "onChildClick: "+childPosition );
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.check1 );
    if( cb != null )
        cb.toggle();
                return false;

            }
        });

    }
```

I think that the problem lies in one of the overridden methods in my adapter.

```
ExpandableListAdapter foodCategoryExpand = new ExpandableListAdapter() {

@Override
Allitemsenabled()

other override methods...


public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    switch (groupPosition) {
    case 0:
    return group1.get(childPosition);
    case 1:
    return group2.get(childPosition);
    case 2:
    return group3.get(childPosition);
    default:
    return null;
    }
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ChildHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(Enter_Foods.this);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.enter_foods_child_helper,null);
        holder.tvChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.enter_foods_exp_lay_child);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
        holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //switch based on which group (main heading) child is in
        switch (groupPosition) {
        case 0:
        holder.tvChild.setText(group1.get(childPosition));
        break;
        case 1:
        holder.tvChild.setText(group2.get(childPosition));
        break;
        case 2:
        holder.tvChild.setText(group3.get(childPosition));
        break;
        }
        return convertView;
}

//create Group (main heading) view
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new GroupHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(Enter_Foods.this);
        //inflate xml file and then get view from that file
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.enter_foods_group_helper,null);
        holder.tvGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.enter_foods_exp_lay_group);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
        holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //this actually gets the text we set in onCreate and sets it to the textView (holder)
        holder.tvGroup.setText(groupTitle.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView; 

}

other override methods
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite figure out the tags stuff you have set up, but I'm quite positive it has something to do with listview recycling. It's repeatedly checking the list items because it's recycling those views. For each View you inflate in getView() make sure you check/uncheck based on some array that you store.

Comment: What do you mean by tag stuff?  I will try messing around with the listview, I assume you are talking about getChildView?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this checkbox issue.

First of all create one

```
ArrayList<String> isCheckedStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
CheckBox check_document;
```

At the time of populating list view fill this arraylist with default "false"

```
for (int i = 0; i < YOUR LIST ITEM ARRAY.size(); i++) {
                        isCheckedStatus.add("false");
                    }
```

Now at the time of checkbox click in your getChildView method

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {if (isCheckedStatus.size() > 0) {
check_document = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary_chk);
                if (isCheckedStatus.get(childPosition).equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                    ((CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary_chk)).setChecked(false);
                } else if (isCheckedStatus.get(childPosition).equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    ((CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary_chk)).setChecked(true);
                }

check_document.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    System.out.println("AAAA  size" + isCheckedStatus.size());
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        if (isCheckedStatus.size() > 0) {
                            isCheckedStatus.remove(childPosition);
                            isCheckedStatus.add(childPosition, "true");

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (isCheckedStatus.size() > 0) {
                            isCheckedStatus.remove(childPosition);
                            isCheckedStatus.add(childPosition, "false");
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
            }
```

This will change the checkbox status everytime when getchildview method is called.
And also resolve your multiple checkbox selection issue.

Hope this work. It's working for me...